# Mysql join query with where and like

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause, sql-like

I have three related tables `users`, `groups` and `group_members`. The users table contains `users` information and `groups`  table contains the group name and group owner id (ie, `users_id`). Table `group_members` contains the members of each groups (`user_id` and `group_id`). I tried to load the users details of each group but the result is not correct. My tables are,

**users**

---

```
id   firstname   lastname    email

1    anu         mm          anu@gmail.com
2    manu        mohan       manu@gmail.com
3    cinu        ab          cinu@gmail.com
4    vinu        mj          vinu@gmail.com
5    vijesh      cc          vijesh@gmail.com
6    admin       admin       admin@gmail.com
```

**groups**

---

```
id     user_id     name

1      1           group1
2      2           group2
3      2           group3
4      3           group4
```

**group_members**

---

```
id    user_id    group_id

1     1          1
2     2          2
3     2          3
4     3          4
5     2          3
7     1          2
8     1          3
9     3          1
```

But when I tried the bellow query,

```
select users.firstname,users.lastname,users.email,groups.name as groupname from users inner join groups on groups.user_id = users.id inner join group_members on group_members.group_id = groups.id where groups.id=3 AND users.firstname LIKE 'cin%' OR users.lastname LIKE 'cin%' OR users.email LIKE 'cin%'
```

getting the result (which is not expected)

---

```
firstname     lastname      email            groupname

cinu          ab            cinu@gmail.com   group4
```

In this case I used the where condition `WHERE groups.id =3` but the result takes the `group4` (groups.id is 4). Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Note that group_members.id is redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your have to use `()` arround your or statements:

```
 where groups.id=3 AND (users.firstname LIKE 'cin%' OR users.lastname LIKE 'cin%' OR users.email LIKE 'cin%')
```

Because `AND` has a higher priority you query looks like:

```
 where (groups.id=3 AND users.firstname LIKE 'cin%') OR users.lastname LIKE 'cin%' OR users.email LIKE 'cin%'
```

And that is not what you  want.